# Protocol error (page.printToPdf) page range exceeds page count Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, pdf-generation

const webPage = await browser.newPage();

```
    await webPage.goto(printUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2',});
    const pdf1Bytes= await webPage.pdf({
        path: filePartOne,
        format: 'Letter',
        printBackground: true,
        preferCSSPageSize: true,
        displayHeaderFooter: true,
        footerTemplate:footer,
        headerTemplate:headerOne,
        defaultFontSize:'40px',
        margin: {
            top: "30mm",
            bottom: "25mm",
            right: "10mm",
            left: "15mm",
        },           
        pageRanges: '1-'+(headerStartPage-1),
       
    });
```

const pdf2Bytes = await  webPage.pdf({
path: filePartTwo,
format: 'Letter',
printBackground: true,
preferCSSPageSize: true,
displayHeaderFooter: true,
footerTemplate:footer,
headerTemplate:headerTwo,
defaultFontSize:'40px',
margin: {
top: "30mm",
bottom: "25mm",
right: "10mm",
left: "15mm",
},
pageRanges: headerStartPage+'-',
});
await browser.close();